# How does one simply submit an html form via dart?

Tags: dom, dart, dart-polymer

This is how one might do it in javascript:  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
How does one do it with dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check type of element:

```
Element form = querySelector("#myForm");
if(form is FormElement){
   form.submit();
}
```

If it doesn't work, try to use iterop. It will be something like this: content("document").call("getElementById",["myForm"]).call("submit",[]);

Comment: Thanks, I've backed off from the specific issue but will give it a shot shortly so that I don't waste your effort!

Comment: Ah, so turns out that I didn't ask the right question because I was assuming too much, but your answer did lead me to the correct solution.  I'm using polymer dart, and I was failing to call shadowRoot.querySelector("#myForm"), and thus #myForm simply wasn't being found.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The simple solution is: (querySelector("#myForm") as FormElement).submit();